# How to create legend d3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I took this example from internet:It works fine except that it creates only two rects. I also fail to see why those rectangles are created since I would expect only one. I created this fiddle which seem not to work. https://jsfiddle.net/q4py7wxg/. Please help.

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
          .range(["rgb(213,222,217)", "rgb(69,173,168)", "rgb(84,36,55)", "rgb(217,91,67)"]);

        var legendText = ["0 - 1000", "1000 - 2000", "2000 - 3000", "3000 - 5000"];
        var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("width", 140)
            .attr("height", 200)
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

        legend.append("rect")
              .attr("width", 18)
              .attr("height", 18)
              .style("fill", color);

        legend.append("text")
              .data(legendText)
              .attr("x", 24)
              .attr("y", 9)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wonder why your code...

> Creates only two rects.

This is the reason: in D3, if you don't set the domain, the default domain is:

```
[0, 1]
```

And that's why you're seeing only two rectangles. Let's see it in this snippet, where `color.domain().slice().reverse()` is the data you're passing in your code:

```js
//look Ma, no domain!
var color = d3.scaleLinear();

console.log(color.domain().slice().reverse());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, your data is an array with only two elements.

**Solution**: first, change your domain:

```
.domain(d3.range(4))
```

Which is the same of:

```
.domain([0,1,2,3])
```

And change your data accordingly:

```
.data(d3.range(4))
```

PS: do not change your data without changing your domain, this will extrapolate the colours, that is, the scale will return colours that are not in the range.

PS2: you're using the wrong scale for the task. It's working (kind of), but it's a strange code to any seasoned d3 coder. Consider using scales with discrete ranges, like `scaleQuantize`, `scaleQuantile` or `scaleThreshold`.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9oxu4xyh/

Answer (score 0):

Your are using the wrong version of D3, try `d3.scaleLinear().` instead of `d3.scale.linear()`

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have that corrected, but how can I have 4 rects rendered given my data.